# How to fix ajax xhr error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically I have a `type="file"`, I need to send chosen file through Ajax, But every time the form gets to submit I am getting a console error which says:

[Error while submitting ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2SP2.png)

here is how I submit myform:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkforImage($('#Propicselecter_file'), "yes");
});
$('[type="file"]').change(function() {
    var fileInput = $(this);
    checkforImage(fileInput, "no");
});
});

function submit_form(){
var fileInput = $('#Propicselecter_file');
$.ajax({
        url: '../propicuploader',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        data: fileInput[0],
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
}

function checkforImage(fileInput, submitornot){
if (fileInput.length && fileInput[0].files && fileInput[0].files.length) {
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      $("#NotPictureerror_spn").text("");
      if(submitornot == "yes"){
        submit_form();

      }
    };
    image.onerror = function() {
      $("#NotPictureerror_spn").text("Chosen file is not an image, Please Try Again");
    };
    image.src = url.createObjectURL(fileInput[0].files[0]);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What does your post look like?

Comment: My `post` contains a file chosen file `type="file"` data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a `formData` object instead of the file object:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
$.ajax({
     url: '../propicuploader',
     type: 'POST',
     processData: false,
     contentType:false, // Added
     data: form_data,
     success: function(data){
   }
});
```

Comment: Now it is sending nothing, just to know I tried `
 alert("FileInput[0]:  + fileInput[0].files[0] + "   form_data: " + form_data);` and the result was `fileInput[0]: [object File]  form_data: [object FormData]`

Comment: @darees Update answer. Try console.log(form_data) and check the log in your console.